# Need to return a value and its count as 0 when it does not exist with in a range of dates

Tags: sql, date, join, constraints

Below is my exact code as it sits. This query works excellent except for when the teamid does not exist inside the date range. If the teamid does not exist within the date range specified, I want SQL to add the teamid to the table and set its count to 0. Then, my table will automatically convert the teamid to the teamtext for me.

```
SELECT tn.teamtext, COUNT(referteamID2) AS cnt
FROM teamnames AS tn
JOIN caseaudit AS ca
ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
WHERE CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10'
AND ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2
AND teamid IN (99, 107, 124, 27, 31, 44, 110, 43, 57, 50, 46)
GROUP BY tn.teamtext
ORDER BY tn.teamtext
```

This returns:

```
4H BOSS                59
ASSET MANAGEMENT       16
BOSS                   5
CUSTOMER SUPPORT       133
NETWORK ENGINEERING    15
PRODUCTION ENGINEERING 142
SECURITY               6
VOICE SERVICES         21
XEROX                  8
```

I was told that the problem may possibly have something to do with using IN after giving the date constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition from the WHERE clause to a CASE statement in the SELECT:

```
SELECT tn.teamtext,
       sum(case when CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10' 
                then 1 else 0
           end) AS cnt
FROM teamnames AS tn JOIN
     caseaudit AS ca
     ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
WHERE ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2 AND
      teamid IN (99, 107, 124, 27, 31, 44, 110, 43, 57, 50, 46)
GROUP BY tn.teamtext
ORDER BY tn.teamtext
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with outer join, although I'm not sure if this is an effective approach:

```
SELECT tn.teamtext, SUM(case when ca.referteamID2 is null then 0 else 1) AS cnt
FROM teamnames AS tn
LEFT OUTER JOIN caseaudit AS ca
ON tn.teamID = ca.referteamID2
WHERE CONVERT(smalldatetime,dModLast,101) BETWEEN '2012-03-01' AND '2012-03-10'
AND ca.referteamid1 <> ca.referteamid2
AND teamid IN (99, 107, 124, 27, 31, 44, 110, 43, 57, 50, 46)
GROUP BY tn.teamtext
ORDER BY tn.teamtext
```

Comment: I tried this before posting the question on here... using an inner or outer join did not make a difference in the output (in my specific case.) However, there are specific cases where this could most definitely be a solution.

Comment: Ah, teamId is from teamnames... try right outer join.. this should work in the right order